# My first CSS project: how do I get the main content not overlapping fixed horizontal menu and footer?

Tags: css

Please help. My brain is fried from doing this first HTML and CSS project.
I've made a fixed horizontal menu at the top and an equally fixed footer. So that they stay on the stupid page no matter how small the browser window is.

But the main content keeps overlapping them both! I have absolutely no idea how to do that, and I will be eternally grateful to whoever can fix my stupid code, who works against me so much!

Please do a good deed and help a girl out.

```css
body { 
  background-color: #D1D0CE;
  font-family:      Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:        small;
  margin:           0px;
}

#content {
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    min-width: 1020px; 
    min-height: 780px; 
}

/* partea de header */

header.top {
    background-color: #F0FFFF;
    margin:           0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:           63px;
}

#headerLogo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#title {
 position:      fixed;
    border:         none;
    top:            1px;
    left:           50%;
    font-family:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:      150%;
    font-weight:    bold;
    color:          #488AC7;
}

/* meniul */


a:link {
    text-decoration:  none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration:  none;
}

.nav {
    background-color:  #488AC7;
 margin:            none;
    position:          fixed;
    width:             100%;
}

.nav ul {
 margin:            0px;
 list-style-type:   none;
 padding:           5px 0px 5px 0px;
}


.nav ul li {
 display:           inline;
 padding:           5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.nav ul li a:link, .nav ul li a:visited {
 color:             #F0FFFF;
 border-bottom:     none;
 font-weight:       bold;
}

.nav ul li.selected {
    background-color:   #F0FFFF;
    border-bottom:      none; 
}

.nav ul li:hover {
    background-color:   #476e9e; 
}

.nav ul li.selected:hover {
    background-color:   #E5E4E2;
}

.nav ul li.selected a:link, .nav ul li.selected a:visited {
    color:              #488AC7;
} 


/* formularul */

form {
 display: table;
 padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

div.tableRow {
 display: table-row;
}

div.tableRow p {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
    padding: 3px; 
}

form input {
height: 20px;

}

div.tableRow p:first-child {
 text-align: left;
    width: 180px;
}

/* tabelul vine aici */

caption {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #488AC7;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

table {
  margin-left:      10px;
  margin-right:     10px;
  margin-top:       10px; 
  border:           thin solid black;
  caption-side:     top;
  border-collapse:  collapse;
  width:            100%;
}

tr.tableHeader {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: left;
}

.tableContent {
 background-color: #F0FFFF;   
}

td, th {
  border:           thin solid gray;
  padding:          5px;
}

/* partea de footer */

.footer {
    margin: 10px 10px 20px 10px; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 1.3px solid #488AC7; 
}

.button {
 background-color:      #488AC7;
 border-radius:         3px;
 border:                1px solid #488AC7;
 display:               inline-block;
 cursor:                pointer;
 color:                 #ffffff;
 font-size:             14px;
 padding:               4px 25px;
 text-decoration:       none;
 text-shadow:           0px 1px 0px #283966;
}
.button:hover {
 background-color:      #476e9e;
}

.button:active {
 position:              relative;
 top:                   1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tema HTML si CSS - saptamana I</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tema.css">
  </head>

  <body>
      
  <div id="content"> 
      
    <header class="top">
        <img id="headerLogo"
           src="images/header_logo.jpg" alt="Assert Banking On Cloud header logo image">
        <p id="title">Data Entry</p>
    </header>  
      
  <div class="mainContent"> 
    <div class="nav">
   <ul>
  <li class="selected"><a href="tema.html">Job Description Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Audit Trail</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Files</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
      
      <br>
      <br>
      
      
    <form action="p" method="post">    
    
    <div class="tableRow"> 
       <p> Basic function and Scope </p>
       <p> <input type="text" name="basic" value="" required></p>
    </div>
          
    <div class="tableRow"> 
        <p> Task and duties </p> 
        <p><input type="text" name="task" value="" required> </p>
    </div>

    <div class="tableRow"> 
        <p> Work contacts </p>
        <p> <input type="text" name="contacts" value="" required> </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tableRow"> 
       <p> Independence of operation</p>
       <p> <input type="text" name="independence" value="" required> </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tableRow"> 
       <p>
  Supervisory responsibility
    </p>
       <p>
            <input type="radio" name="suptype" value="supervision" checked> Supervision
            <input type="radio" name="suptype" value="direction"> Direction
           <input type="radio" name="suptype" value="none"> None
       </p>
    </div>
        
     <div class="tableRow"> 
         <p> </p>
         <p> <input type="text" name="textSupervisory" value="">
    </p>
    </div>
         
    <div class="tableRow"> 
       <p> Total number of subordinates </p>
       <p> <input type="text" name="subordinates" value="" readonly>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="tableRow"> 
        <p> Physical effort </p>
        <p> <input type="text" name="physical" value=""> 
    </p>
    </div>
        
   <div class="tableRow"> 
       <p> Work conditions </p>
       <p> <input type="text" name="conditions" value="">
    </p>
    </div> 
        

      
</form>
      
      
      
    <table>
      <caption>
        Minimum requirements
      </caption>
      <tr class="tableHeader">
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
        <th>Header 5</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 1 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 2 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 2 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 2 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 2 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 3 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 3 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 3 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 3 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 3 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 4 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 4 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 4 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 4 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 4 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 5 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 5 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 5 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 5 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 5 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 6 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 6 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 6 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 6 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 6 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>      

  </div>
      
  <div class="footer">
        <a href="#" class="button">Save</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Submit</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Cancel</a>
    </div>
      
 </div>       
      
    
</body>
```

Comment: can you give me more info? where do I use it? on the main text class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that your `header.top` needs to be `position:fixed` and it needs a defined width. Right now only its children are `position:fixed`, so its background still scrolls with the page. And if it has zero width the background will be invisible.

```
header.top {
    background-color: #F0FFFF;
    margin:           0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:           63px;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed; top:0;
}
```

Once you set the header to fixed, its height is removed from the document flow, so you need to add `.mainContent {margin-top:63px;}` to keep the content from hiding under your header before you start scrolling.

As for your footer, it has no background defined and is transparent without one. I gave it a background and changed the margins so it sits in the corner.

```css
body { 
  background-color: #D1D0CE;
  font-family:      Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:        small;
  margin:           0px;
}

#content {
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    min-width: 1020px; 
    min-height: 780px; 
}

/* partea de header */

.mainContent {margin-top:63px;}

header.top {
    background-color: #F0FFFF;
    margin:           0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:           63px;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed; top:0;
}

#headerLogo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#title {
 position:      fixed;
    border:         none;
    top:            1px;
    left:           50%;
    font-family:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:      150%;
    font-weight:    bold;
    color:          #488AC7;
}

/* meniul */


a:link {
    text-decoration:  none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration:  none;
}

.nav {
    background-color:  #488AC7;
 margin:            none;
    position:          fixed;
    width:             100%;
}

.nav ul {
 margin:            0px;
 list-style-type:   none;
 padding:           5px 0px 5px 0px;
}


.nav ul li {
 display:           inline;
 padding:           5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.nav ul li a:link, .nav ul li a:visited {
 color:             #F0FFFF;
 border-bottom:     none;
 font-weight:       bold;
}

.nav ul li.selected {
    background-color:   #F0FFFF;
    border-bottom:      none; 
}

.nav ul li:hover {
    background-color:   #476e9e; 
}

.nav ul li.selected:hover {
    background-color:   #E5E4E2;
}

.nav ul li.selected a:link, .nav ul li.selected a:visited {
    color:              #488AC7;
} 


/* formularul */

form {
 display: table;
 padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

div.tableRow {
 display: table-row;
}

div.tableRow p {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
    padding: 3px; 
}

form input {
height: 20px;

}

div.tableRow p:first-child {
 text-align: left;
    width: 180px;
}

/* tabelul vine aici */

caption {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #488AC7;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

table {
  margin-left:      10px;
  margin-right:     10px;
  margin-top:       10px; 
  border:           thin solid black;
  caption-side:     top;
  border-collapse:  collapse;
  width:            100%;
}

tr.tableHeader {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: left;
}

.tableContent {
 background-color: #F0FFFF;   
}

td, th {
  border:           thin solid gray;
  padding:          5px;
}

/* partea de footer */

.footer {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 1.3px solid #488AC7; 
    background:#f0ffff;
}

.button {
 background-color:      #488AC7;
 border-radius:         3px;
 border:                1px solid #488AC7;
 display:               inline-block;
 cursor:                pointer;
 color:                 #ffffff;
 font-size:             14px;
 padding:               4px 25px;
 text-decoration:       none;
 text-shadow:           0px 1px 0px #283966;
}
.button:hover {
 background-color:      #476e9e;
}

.button:active {
 position:              relative;
 top:                   1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tema HTML si CSS - saptamana I</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tema.css">
  </head>

  <body>
      
  <div id="content"> 
      
    <header class="top">
        <img id="headerLogo"
           src="images/header_logo.jpg" alt="Assert Banking On Cloud header logo image">
        <p id="title">Data Entry</p>
    </header>  
      
  <div class="mainContent"> 
    <div class="nav">
   <ul>
  <li class="selected"><a href="tema.html">Job Description Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Audit Trail</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Files</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
      
      <br>
      <br>
      
      
    <form action="p" method="post">    
    
    <div class="tableRow"> 
       <p> Basic function and Scope </p>
       <p> <input type="text" name="basic" value="" required></p>
    </div>
          
    <div class="tableRow"> 
        <p> Task and duties </p> 
        <p><input type="text" name="task" value="" required> </p>
    </div>

    <div class="tableRow"> 
        <p> Work contacts </p>
        <p> <input type="text" name="contacts" value="" required> </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tableRow"> 
       <p> Independence of operation</p>
       <p> <input type="text" name="independence" value="" required> </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tableRow"> 
       <p>
  Supervisory responsibility
    </p>
       <p>
            <input type="radio" name="suptype" value="supervision" checked> Supervision
            <input type="radio" name="suptype" value="direction"> Direction
           <input type="radio" name="suptype" value="none"> None
       </p>
    </div>
        
     <div class="tableRow"> 
         <p> </p>
         <p> <input type="text" name="textSupervisory" value="">
    </p>
    </div>
         
    <div class="tableRow"> 
       <p> Total number of subordinates </p>
       <p> <input type="text" name="subordinates" value="" readonly>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="tableRow"> 
        <p> Physical effort </p>
        <p> <input type="text" name="physical" value=""> 
    </p>
    </div>
        
   <div class="tableRow"> 
       <p> Work conditions </p>
       <p> <input type="text" name="conditions" value="">
    </p>
    </div> 
        

      
</form>
      
      
      
    <table>
      <caption>
        Minimum requirements
      </caption>
      <tr class="tableHeader">
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
        <th>Header 5</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 1 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 1 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 1 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 2 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 2 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 2 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 2 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 3 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 3 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 3 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 3 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 3 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 4 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 4 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 4 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 4 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 4 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 5 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 5 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 5 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 5 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 5 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableContent">
        <td>Row 6 Cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 6 Cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 6 Cell 3</td>  
        <td>Row 6 Cell 4</td>
        <td>Row 6 Cell 5</td>
      </tr>
    </table>      

  </div>
      
  <div class="footer">
        <a href="#" class="button">Save</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Submit</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">Cancel</a>
    </div>
      
 </div>       
      
    
</body>
```

Comment: just one more thing: could you work your magic so that the white footer background extends to width: 100%, and not just around the buttons? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I've tried .footer {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 90px; but it looks weird and the buttons are on top of each other

Comment: Did you try giving `width: 100%` to `.footer`? ;-)  You'll then notice that the buttons jump to the left edge of the footer, you'll want to wrap them in a `<span>` tag and add the rule `.footer > span {float:right;}`

Comment: Actually, easier than that, just add `width: 100%; text-align: right;` to `.footer`.

Comment: it was so easy and THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH!!! You have no idea how  bad I've felt thinking I'll go to work with a partially-done homework! (it's a company internship, I'm a business analyst btw). THANK YOU!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixed, use absolute and change the footer bottom to 1. It is working fine for me doing that.

```
body { 
  background-color: #D1D0CE;
  font-family:      Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:        small;
  margin:           0px;
}

#content {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    min-width: 1020px; 
    min-height: 780px; 
}

/* partea de header */

header.top {
    background-color: #F0FFFF;
    margin:           0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:           63px;
}

#headerLogo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#title {
    position:      absolute;
    border:         none;
    top:            1px;
    left:           50%;
    font-family:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:      150%;
    font-weight:    bold;
    color:          #488AC7;
}

/* meniul */


a:link {
    text-decoration:  none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration:  none;
}

.nav {
    background-color:  #488AC7;
    margin:            none;
    position:          absolute;
    width:             100%;
}

.nav ul {
    margin:            0px;
    list-style-type:   none;
    padding:           5px 0px 5px 0px;
}


.nav ul li {
    display:           inline;
    padding:           5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.nav ul li a:link, .nav ul li a:visited {
    color:             #F0FFFF;
    border-bottom:     none;
    font-weight:       bold;
}

.nav ul li.selected {
    background-color:   #F0FFFF;
    border-bottom:      none; 
}

.nav ul li:hover {
    background-color:   #476e9e; 
}

.nav ul li.selected:hover {
    background-color:   #E5E4E2;
}

.nav ul li.selected a:link, .nav ul li.selected a:visited {
    color:              #488AC7;
} 


/* formularul */

form {
    display: table;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

div.tableRow {
    display: table-row;
}

div.tableRow p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 3px; 
}

form input {
height: 20px;

}

div.tableRow p:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    width: 180px;
}

/* tabelul vine aici */

caption {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #488AC7;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

table {
  margin-left:      10px;
  margin-right:     10px;
  margin-top:       10px; 
  border:           thin solid black;
  caption-side:     top;
  border-collapse:  collapse;
  width:            100%;
}

tr.tableHeader {
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: left;
}

.tableContent {
 background-color: #F0FFFF;   
}

td, th {
  border:           thin solid gray;
  padding:          5px;
}

/* partea de footer */

.footer {
    margin: 10px 10px 20px 10px; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 1.3px solid #488AC7; 
}

.button {
    background-color:      #488AC7;
    border-radius:         3px;
    border:                1px solid #488AC7;
    display:               inline-block;
    cursor:                pointer;
    color:                 #ffffff;
    font-size:             14px;
    padding:               4px 25px;
    text-decoration:       none;
    text-shadow:           0px 1px 0px #283966;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color:      #476e9e;
}

.button:active {
    position:              relative;
    top:                   1px;
}
```

Comment: but with absolute the header will be gone from the page when scrolling down... which I don't want. I've tried your suggestion just now.

Answer (score 0):

Change the fixed to absolute in #headerLogo and #title.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I have added a div with the class scrollable and the following css.

```
.scrollable{overflow-y: auto;height:100px;}
```

This requirement from your teacher is quite ugly and not practical, needed a hardcoded height value, your design was very nice, but oh well, customer and teacher is king:-)

what I have done here is wrap everything between header and footer in a div with y scroll set to auto

Link to codepen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/rxJZev

Comment: but it is already above.. the problem is the main content keeps getting under the damn thing.

Comment: Lol, Emma, you can't have it both ways, in your OP, you said you don't want the main content to overlap the header/footer, now you say you do not want the content to be overlapped.
So, which one is it?

Comment: It's an awful requirement, I know. My teacher is trying to kill me, it seems. So the first requirement is this: have the header and footer present on the page at all times, no matter how small the window is. This I've done with the fixed positioning. BUT the second requirement is, the content to fit between them, using scroll bars.

Comment: To be clear, you want the header and footer to be fixed and then, what is supposed to happen with the content?
Ah ok, I think i have got it now, let me try.

Comment: the content to fit using scroll bars. Is it an awful requirement or what?

Comment: nah its rather simple, actually

Comment: simple? please please please please write it for me

Comment: damiano? still there?

Comment: @EmmaZ
Yeah, have a look at the pen now, i have also changed the reply above and explained how I have done it. You can play around with the height value of the new div, and well the footer might need some repositioning.

Comment: I've checked the pen again and it seems the same? Maybe it's my fried brain, but I still see the text sweeping under the header. In the meantime, I've added a background image for the header and... it's sort of working, considering now I can't see the damn title.

Comment: @EmmaZ

oops, i had forgotten one thing, go check now:-)

Comment: @EmmaZ
While this made a scrollbar appear, I have now removed the scrollbar, check the pen, now it looks tidy and works flawlessly.